# Classification of elements $GL(d, \mathbb{R})$

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-theory

Any $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ is either elliptic or hyperbolic, or parabolic up to conjugacy; [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SL2(R)).

Do we have the same classification for $GL(d, \mathbb{R})$? If so, could you please introduce some references? I meant that it is true that any $GL(d, \mathbb{R})$ matrix is either elliptic or hyperbolic or parabolic up to conjugacy.

Comment: You should learn about reduction theory, Jordan decomposition and so on. Your last question "Is it true..." is senseless if you don't define "elliptic", "hyperbolic" and "parabolic". (And in $SL_2$ every matrix is elliptic, hyperbolic or parabolic. No "up to conjugacy" needed.)

Comment: Normally hyperbolic means that no power has an iinvariant proper subspace, parabolic means that some power has an invariant proper subspace but the element is not torsion and elliptic means torsion. Since in dim $\ge 3$ every matrix has  invariant  $2-$dim subspace, you won't have hyperbolic matrices if $d\ge3$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices

Comment: As the comments suggest, there are many different ways in which you can interpret the words in this question. One interpretation is via actions on metric spaces. Given an isometry $\phi$ of a metric space $X$, consider the displacement $|\phi|=\inf_{x\in X}d(x,\phi(x))$. An isometry is *hyperbolic* of the infimum is positive and realised, *elliptic* if it's 0 and realised, and *parabolic* if it's not realised. For the action of $GL(d,\mathbb{R})$ on its associated symmetric space, this generalises the standard classification for $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$. See §II.6 of Bridson and Haefliger.